# Is there a Java class that is a cross between a Map and a List?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am looking for a Java class that offers both `Map` (fast lookup) and `List` (determinate order) characteristics.  Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) preserves the order elements are added into collection.

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) keeps the keys in order